# Proof Check: Exercise III.7.4 in A Course in Homological Algebra by Hilton and Stammbach

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, homological-algebra

> Show that if $A,B$ are $R-$modules and if $\sum_i a_i\otimes b_i=0$ in $A\otimes_R B$, then there are finitely generated submodules $A_0\subseteq A$, $B_0\subseteq B$ such that $a_i\in A_0$, $b_i\in B_0$ and $\sum_i a_i\otimes b_i=0$ in $A_0\otimes_R B_0$. Use this to prove $\mathbb{Q}$ is flat over $\mathbb{Z}$.

Proof of "$\mathbb{Q}$ is a flat $\mathbb{Z}-$module": For any monomorphism $u: A\rightarrow B$, we must show that the induced map $u_*: A\otimes \mathbb{Q}\rightarrow B\otimes \mathbb{Q}$ is also monomorphic. Let $u_*(a\otimes x)=u(a)\otimes x=0$, then we may suppose that $a$ is not a torsion element since otherwise $a\otimes x=0$ ($\mathbb{Q}$ is divisible) and we're done. Applying the first part of the exercise, we can find $B_0\subseteq B$, $\mathbb{Q}_0\subseteq \mathbb{Q}$ that are finitely generated and contain $u(a)$ and $x$, respectively, satisfying $u(a)\otimes x=0$ in $B_0\otimes \mathbb{Q}_0$. Since every finitely generated subgroup of $\mathbb{Q}$ is cyclic, there exist $y\in\mathbb{Q}$ such that $\mathbb{Q}_0=\langle y \rangle$ and we have $x=ky$ for some $k\in\mathbb{Z}$. So $k(u(a)\otimes y)=0$.

We have $\langle u(a)\rangle\otimes\mathbb{Q}_0\cong\langle u(a)\rangle\otimes\mathbb{Z}$ via $su(a)\otimes my\mapsto su(a)\otimes m$ (observing that $u(a)$ is not torsion, the map is injective). Hence $\langle u(a)\rangle\otimes\mathbb{Q}_0\cong\langle u(a)\rangle\cong\mathbb{Z}$ and it's torsion-free. Since $k(u(a)\otimes y)=0$ and $u(a)\otimes y$ cannot be zero, we must get $k=0$ and $x=0$. Thus $u_*$ is monomorphic.

I'm new to the concept of tensor product, so i'm not sure whether my proof is corrrect. Any helps will be appreciated.

Comment: To start, $$(\forall a \in A) (\forall  x \in \mathbb Q)[u^*(a \otimes x) = 0 \implies a \otimes x = 0]$$ doesn't prove that $u^*$ is a monomorphism, $$(\forall t \in A \otimes \mathbb Q)[u^*(t) \implies t=0]$$ does.

Comment: @azif00: Thanks for pointing out my mistake! Another attempt: $\forall t\in A\otimes\mathbb{Q}$, let $t=\sum k_i (a_i\otimes x_i)=\sum (k_i a_i\otimes x_i)$. Suppose $u^*(t)=\sum (u(k_i a_i)\otimes x_i)=0$. There exists a finitely generated subgroup $\mathbb{Q}_0\subseteq\mathbb{Q}$ such that $x_i\in\mathbb{Q}_0$ and $\sum (u(k_i a_i)\otimes x_i)=0$ in $B\otimes\mathbb{Q}_0$. Since $\mathbb{Q}_0$ is cyclic, it's free and thus flat. Hence $u\otimes 1:A\otimes \mathbb{Q}_0\rightarrow B\otimes \mathbb{Q}_0$ is injective. Since $(u\otimes 1)(t)=0$, we have $t=0$.